# Facebook PHP SDK getLogoutUrl

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the context of a facebook application what is the point in this? Since they cannot play your app till authorised and logged in. What purpose does logging them out of a facebook session and redirected to your app actually serve?

```
This method returns a URL that, when clicked by the user, will log them out of their      Facebook session and then redirect them back to your application.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful outside Facebook, in the context where the user authenticates via Facebook to log into your website.

Comment: Yeah, ok, is about the only use case I could think of for it for an application which actually sits within facebook already.